No Selenium version that supports CDP version 128 ( Latest Chrome version )
AVERTISSEMENT: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 128, returning the closest version; found: 127; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 128
I'm using the latest version of Selenium 4.23.1 and the the latest version of Chrome 128.0.6613.84
I can't find a Selenium version that matches my latest Chrome version

I found a way to fix it
Search for the dependency in the maven site
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools-v128
Add the dependency
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v128</artifactId>
        <version>4.24.0</version>
    </dependency>

The chromedriver version must be compatible with the chrome version 128. And Selenium version should be 4.24
https://getwebdriver.com/chromedriver#stable

Yes they recently added the 4.24.0 version. Thanks for your contribution.
